# MAMP Start Page Only Shows Index

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to install Wordpress on MAMP using [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP) tutorial. When I start the MAMP server and go to the MAMP startup page, I see this index instead of a GUI. As a result, I can't access the PHPMyAdmin GUI (despite the PHPMyAdmin link) to create a database for Wordpress. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I'm running OSX 10.9.5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try that url to access phpmyadmin
http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/

Comment: It just returns an index listing of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the directory listing that Apache provides in some cases. When a folder is requested, Apache looks in a folder for a file name matching the `DirectoryIndex` directive, which are often files such as index.php, index.html, home.htm, and so on. Since none of those exist here, the directory listing is shown.

Basically, something isn't right here with your MAMP install; either this URL is not designed to be accessed by you ever or your installation is incomplete. First, try loading `http://localhost:8888` directly and see if that works any better for you. Failing that, I suggest you make a backup of any MAMP related files (databases, web pages, or configuration changes) and reinstall. One possible cause of this is if the MAMP package is not installed to /Applications/

In short, when you're using an all-in-one package like MAMP this shouldn't happen. You say that when you uninstalled and reinstalled that fixed the problem which is what I would have suggested anyway. It seems something went wrong with the installation and that should (and did) fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I add the solution that helped me in the similar situation just in case someone later will face the same problem when after the Wordpress has been installed, a browser just show "Index of/" instead of the required site.

Check the following points:

1. There is 'index.php' file in the root folder of your project. (web server tries to open exactly this file).
2. If the file actually is located there, check the configuration of your web server. For example in my case my web server is Apache 2.4. After I added the directive "DirectoryIndex index.php" in the Apache configurations file (thereby saying to the server which file it should open if it received the address of the root folder) my problem was solved.